# Requirejs "text!" plugin alternative to webpack

Tags: javascript, requirejs, migration, webpack

How to make this work in webpack?

```
var templateHtml = require("text!templates/main.html");
console.log(templateHtml); // outputs string content of the "main.html" file
```

I need to migrate from requirejs + require-text plugin to webpack with minimum code changes so I need that loader in webpack... Have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should use 'text-loader': https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-loader

My mistake was that I used both `text!` notation in `require` and `loaders` config with "text-loader".

Comment: Hi Dimitry, I'm in similar situation. Can you explain what did you do? I saw this question after posting my question  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691170/migrating-requirejs-and-backbone-based-application-to-webpack).   Would like to have your inputs. Thanks

Comment: You need to install the text-loader plugin via npm install. No extra config is needed.

Comment: just install text-loader npm package locally & add alias: {
        "text!": "text-loader!"
    } this in webpack.config file

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer mentions, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/text-loader. With Webpack 2.2, I also needed to add the following to the root of the Webpack config object:

```
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        // Support for require('text!file.json').
        'text': 'full/path/to/node_modules/text-loader'
    }
}
```